# Video player with very slow playback speed, for Windows

Tags: windows, video-player

I am looking for a video player which can play an mp4 video with speed 0.05 (5%) of the original, audio is not important. I tried WMP and VLC but the slowest seting is only 25%.

[Edit]

It is not necessary for the video to play smoothly. What I need is to play it slowly. So, perhaps software that would allow to play frame by frame would suffice.

So far I found a workaround to "play" (or rather click through) the video frame by frame in 3 ways:

1. Windows Media Player: Ctrl+Click the Play button to go to next frame. The output is ok.
2. VLC: press "e" to go to next frame (also View->Advanced Controls). The output is with pixelated artifacts.
3. Upload video to Youtube and in fullscreen press "." to go to next frame, "," to go to prev frame.

But I am looking for a way to **play the video automatically, or to present frames sequentially at given speed without the need of manual input**.

Comment: you can change playspeed in VLC as well https://www.vlchelp.com/controlling-playback-speed-vlc-media-player/

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken this is a bit of a factual limit. Since most videos are usually like 25-30 fps (frames per second), slowing them to one frame per second is something like the lowest point.

I did, however, found this online service [**Video speed changer**](https://ezgif.com/video-speed) that you can set to **0.05** and it will generate you a file that much stretched. Although I didn't check exactly how they do the slowing (displaying each frame for several seconds?)

I did find such an option in the [**VSDC Free Video Editor**](http://www.videosoftdev.com/free-video-editor). Although it might be an overkill since it is a full-fledged video editor, it does the job nicely.

You **Import** the video and then set the **Speed** to 5 (%). Then do **Export Project**

[image]

Comment: I uploaded the 4 minutes (54MB) video, changed speed to 0.05 and the output video is 13 min (20MB). The speed and resolution is ok, but it's too short, maybe there is a limit but I didn't notice.

Comment: You are right it's close to fps limit, but see my edited question.

Comment: I tested again and also had mixed results with the site, some clips it would work and for others not. Added another option.